# does javascript on iphone mobile safari support xpath?

Tags: javascript, iphone, xpath, safari

does javascript on iphone mobile safari support xpath? I am using libxml2 to parse xhtml files in objective-c, but want to be able to change my parsing logic on the fly. Was considering using UIWebview's stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method.

Answer (score 1):

I see that version 3.0 has `document.evaluate` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate That's all you should need for XPATH evaluation.

Comment: document.evaluate is not working in Simulator 3.0 or Simulator 3.1.

I'm running the following inside webViewDidFinishLoad, where the page that was loaded has 2 <form> elements, and the result of the evaluation is zero.

scriptCode = @"document.evaluate(\"count(//form)\", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;";
            
result = [thewebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:scriptCode];

Comment: Have you tried using `snapshotLength`, rather than xpath's `count`? `document.evaluate("//form", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotLength`